# Clean Break Between Panels Without Using Transparent Panels

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a clean break between panels of my horizontal scrolling website for my architectural portfolio. The break allows the light effect behind the panels to show giving a nice break between projects. At the very beginning and end of the site, there is a nice glowing effect that I created to make it look backlit. I have not been able to create this break between project panels.

I tried to put transparent panels in and that obviously didn't work. I tried to break it by ending a project by ending the wrapper and the page wrapper and starting a new wrapper and page wrapper. These do put a break between panels, but nothing is working the way I need it to. The ways I tried to do what I want only made it look like there is just a blank, or missing panel. It looks like a mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
     portfolio
-->
<html>
    <head>
    <title>VK | p o r t f o l i o</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

<div id="page-wrapper">
<div id="wrapper">

            <!--------------------------- Panel TITLE VK portfolio ------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="inner columns color6">
            <div class="span-4">                            
            <div>
            <p>portfolio</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </section>  

            <!------------------- FADE RIGHT ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfaderight span-1">
            </div>
            </section>

            <!----------- TABLE OF CONTENTS ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel colortableofcontents" id="tableofcontents">
            <div class="inner columns">
            <div class="span-7">                                    
            <div class="table-wrapper">

                <table style="font-size: 20px;">
                <table style="color: rgb(255,215,0) !important;">                                           
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><a href="#nhcc">new haven <b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">country club</b> </a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#111"> <b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">111 west lane</b> | private residence</a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#js"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">benjamin jepson school</b> <br>| new haven public schools</a></td>
                </tr>
                                                
                <tr>
                <td><a href="#br"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">brookside & rockview</b> | urban development</a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#uconn">university of connecticut | <b style="color: rgb(255,215,0);"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">school of fine arts</b></a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#ocean">oceania cruises | ships <b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">marina</b> | <b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">riviera</b></a></td>
                </tr>
                                                
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#188"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">188 front street</b> | private residence</a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#ao"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">acorn one</b> | acorn technology campus</a></td>
                </tr>
                                            
                <tr>
                <td><a href="#ph"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">scottsdale house</b> | private residence</a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#bw"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">bishop woods school</b><br> | new haven public schools</a></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="#cs"><b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">clemente school</b> | new haven public schools</a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><a href="#lib">yale studio | <b style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255,215,0);">library</b></a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>  
            </section>
            <!----------------------------------------------------- END TABLE OF CONTENTS --------------------------------------------------------------->

            <!-------------------------------------------- FADES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfadeleft span-1">
            </div>
            </section>

            <section class="panel">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfaderight span-1">
            </div>
            </section>
            <!------------------------------------------------ NHCC -------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel colornhcctartan" id="nhcc">
            <div class="inner columns aligned">

                <section class="panel">
                <div class="span-3">                                    
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    
                    <td><h1><br><br></h1></td>

                    <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <td>consultant</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>complete renovation</b></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><b>designer | project manager</b></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="right">builder | <b>petra</b> construction corp.</td>
                    </tr>
                                    
                    <tr>
                    <td><h1 style="color: rgba(23, 76, 112, 0.959);">new haven<br> country club</h1></td>
                    <td><b>1898</b></td>
                    <td align="right"><b>clubhouse</b><br> & golf course</td>
                    </tr>
                                    
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>                                        
                    </td>
                    <td align="right"><b>lake whitney</b></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>hamden, connecticut</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><b></b></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>  
                </div>
                </section>                  
                <!-- Panel Table NHCC -->

                <!-- GALLERY Panel NHCC -->
                <section class="panel">
                <div class="gallery">
                            
                    <div class="group span-6">
                    <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc02.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="25% 75%"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc02bw.jpg" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc92.jpg" class="image span-4" data-position="top"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc92t.jpg" alt="" style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                    <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc10.jpg" class="image span-2" data-position="right"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc10.jpg" alt="" style="border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </section>

                <!-- Panel -->
                <div class="span-2-25">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h4>NHCC</h4>                       
                    <h8><p>
                    <b>New Haven Country Club</b> was founded in <b>1898</b> as one of the very <b>early golf courses</b> built in the United States. Yale professor Theodore Woolsey is credited with being the driving force behind the club’s incorporation and much of its early development. Land was purchased next to <b>beautiful Lake Whitney</b> which is a natural lake preserved by the New Haven Water company. The original golf course was laid out, and construction of the clubhouse began in 1899.<br>

                    <br>“…<b>New Haven Country Club is today the leading social organization of the city.</b> A handsome stone clubhouse was erected last fall of the <b>Old English pattern</b> similar to the <b>clubhouses</b> on the courses in <b>England and Scotland</b>. A restaurant famous for its excellence is maintained the year round. In the clubhouse, far from the noise and bustle of the city, many of the largest social entertainments of <b>the smart set</b> are held.”
                    <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <br><span style="display: inline-block; text-indent: 1em;"><b>----The Connecticut Magazine, Spring 1900</b></span>
                    </p></h8>
                </div>

            </div>
            </section>
            <!-- Panel END NHCC -->

            <!-- GALLERY Panel NHCC -->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="gallery">

                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc07.jpg" class="image span-5" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc07.jpg" alt="" /></a>

            <div class="group span-4-5">
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc17.jpg" class="image span-4-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc17.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc81.jpg" class="image span-4-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc81t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>

                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc16.jpg" class="image span-5" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc16.jpg" alt="" /></a> 

            <div class="group span-3">                  
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc60.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc60t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc05.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc05.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>                                  
                        
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc18.jpg" class="image span-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc18.jpg" alt="" /></a>

            <div class="group span-4">
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc82.jpg" class="image span-2" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc82t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc83.jpg" class="image span-2" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc83t.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc08.jpg" class="image span-4" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc08.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc01.jpg" class="image span-8" data-position="25% 75%"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc01.jpg" alt="" /></a>    
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/nhcc04.jpg" class="image span-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/nhcc04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            </section>
            <!-- GALLERY Panel NHCC -->

            <!-- Panel TABLE NHCC -->
            <section class="panel colornhcc">
            <div class="inner columns">
            <div class="span-2">                                    
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>
                <tbody>
                <h2>NHCC</h2> 
                <td><b>Awards:</b></td>
                <tr>
                <td><br></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>2008 AGCCT Build Connecticut Award</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                                
                <tr>
                <td>2007 CT-ABC Excellence in Construction Award</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                                
                <tr>
                <td>2007 ABC Excellence in Construction Award Certificate of Commendation</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <!--------------------------------------------- END NHCC ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

            <!-- Panel FADE -->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfaderight span-1">
            </div>
            </section>

            <!---------------------------------------------- BEGIN BISHOP WOODS ----------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <!-- Panel TABLE -->
            <section class="panel colorbishop" id="bw">
            <div class="inner columns">
            <div class="span-3">                                    
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>                                         
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><b>designer | project manager</b></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><h1 style="color: rgba(138, 182, 195);">bishop woods school</h1></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>new haven, connecticut</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>new haven public schools</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <p><h1><br></h1></p>
                </table>

                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#nhcc" class="button small">previous project</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#tableofcontents" class="button small">portfolio index</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#cs" class="button small">next project</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>  
            </section>
            <!-- Panel TABLE -->    

            <!-- GALLERY Panel BISHOP WOODS -->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="gallery">

                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/bw00.jpg" class="image span-5" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/bw00.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188);"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/bw01.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/bw01.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188);"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/bw02.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/bw02.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188);"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/bw03.jpg" class="image span-7" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/bw03.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(134, 176, 188);"/></a>

            </div>
            </section>
            <!---------------------------------------------- END BISHOP WOODS ------------------------------------------------------------------------->

            <!-- BLANK Panel -->
            <section class="panel" style="border-left: 1px solid black;">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfadeclemente span-1">
            </div>
            </section>

            <!---------------------------------------- BEGIN CLEMENTE SCHOOL -------------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <section class="panel colorclemente" id="cs">
            <div class="inner columns">
            <div class="span-3">                                    
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>                                         
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><b>designer | project manager</b></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><h1 style="color: rgba(0, 28, 0, 0.801);"> clemente school</h1></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>new haven, connecticut</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>builder | <b>giordano construction</td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">new haven public schools</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <p><h1><br></h1></p>
                </table>

                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#bw" class="button small">previous project</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#tableofcontents" class="button small">portfolio index</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block;">
                    <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><a href="#js" class="button small">next project</a></li>
                    </ul>
            
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>  
            </section>
            <!-- Panel TABLE -->    

            <!-- GALLERY Panel CS -->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="gallery">

                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs00.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs00.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs03.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs03.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs01.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs01.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs04.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="bottom"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs04.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                
                <div class="group span-6">
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs07.jpg" class="image span-4" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs07.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
                <img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs91.jpg" alt="" class="image span-2" data-position="center" />
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs02.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="top"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs02.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs90.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs90.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/cs05.jpg" class="image span-4" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/cs05.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>

            </div>
            </section>
            <!----------------------------------------- END CLEMENTE SCHOOL ---------------------------------------------------------------->   

            <section class="panel" style="border-left: 1px solid transparent;">
            <div class="intro colorpanelfadejepson span-1-5">
            </div>
            </section>

            <!-------------------------------------------- BEGIN JEPSON ----------------------------------------------------------------------->
            <!-- Panel TABLE JEPSON -->
            <section class="panel colorjepson" id="js">
            <div class="inner columns">
            <div class="span-3">                                    
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>                                         
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td><b>designer | project manager</b></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><h1 style="color: rgba(126, 198, 187);">jepson school</h1></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>new haven, connecticut</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>new haven public schools</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <p><h1><br></h1></p>
                </table>

                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#cs" class="button small">previous project</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#tableofcontents" class="button small">portfolio index</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <p style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-size: 0px;"> transparent text</p>
                <ul class="actions">
                <li><a href="#uconn" class="button small">next project</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>  
            </section>
            <!-- Panel TABLE -->
                
            <!-- GALLERY Panel JEPSON -->
            <section class="panel">
            <div class="gallery">
                
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/js01.jpg" class="image span-3" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/js01.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>

                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/js02.jpg" class="image span-6" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/js02.jpg" alt="" /></a>

                <div class="group span-2">
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/js20.jpg" class="image span-2" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/js20.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/js22.jpg" class="image span-2" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/js22.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
            
                <a href="images/gallery/fulls/js04.jpg" class="image span-8" data-position="center"><img src="images/gallery/thumbs/js04.jpg" alt="" style="border-left: 1px solid black;"/></a>    

            </div>
            </section>
            <!--------------------------------------------- END JEPSON SCHOOL ------------------------------------------------------------------>   

                
    <!-- THIS </div> IS THE inner Wrapper ENTIRE PAGE -->
    </div>

        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</div>

    <!-- THIS </div> IS THE OUTER PAGE Wrapper ENTIRE PAGE -->
    </div>

            <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```